# Inferred type of function argument is 'never' but supplied argument is correct

Tags: typescript

I have some simplified TypeScript code that shows an issue I'm having with typing. The first bit of the code below shows a composable that returns a factory function. This factory function returns a function of type A or B depending on an argument.

There is also a function `test`. `test` takes two arguments with the type of the second one being restricted by the type of the first one.

The reason it's structured that way is because it comes from a Vue project where this composable pattern is very common.

```
type A = (arg: 'A') => void
type B = (arg: 'B') => void

const a: A = (arg: 'A') => { }
const b: B = (arg: 'B') => { }

function useComposable<T extends boolean>(arg: T) {
  type MyType = T extends true ? A : B

  function factory(): MyType {
    return (arg ? a : b) as MyType
  }

  return { factory }
}

type ArgType<R extends boolean> = Parameters<
  ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof useComposable<R>>['factory']>
>[0]


function test<T extends boolean>(composableArg: T, funcArg: ArgType<T>) {
  const { factory } = useComposable(composableArg)

  const f = factory()

  f(funcArg) // This is not allowed, I want to fix this
};

// OK
test(true, 'A')
// NOK as expected
test(true, 'B')
```

The problem I have occurs when calling `f`. Since there is no overlap between the arguments of A and B (`'A'` or `'B'`), TypeScript infers the argument type of `f` as never. This marks `f(funcArg)` as invalid. How can I solve this? `funcArg` is of type `ArgType<T>`, so I know that it should work with `f`. This can be seen when calling `test`. Why is this not enough?

This could be workaround but I find it unacceptable: `f(funcArg as never)`.

EDIT: improved code example for clarity.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're doing or why you're sure `f(funcArg)` is valid.  I don't see any restrictions in that code that would guarantee you're not passing `"A"` to `B` or `"B"` to `A`.  Your `ArgType` type is just `"A" | "B"`, not some conditional generic thing.  My *guess* is that you intend `composableArg`'s type and `ArgType` to be some kind of "correlated union", as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), but that's not what you're showing here... and even if you did, TS has no direct support for it.

Comment: (see prev comment)  The easiest workaround is just use a type assertion (what you're calling "cast") but you find it unacceptable (presumably `const f = factory() as (arg: ArgType) => void;` is equally unacceptable?) so I'm not sure what to tell you.  There might be a hefty refactoring following [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) involving generics but I doubt it's worth the effort.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz I have created a TS playground to better explain the link between the two values: https://shorturl.at/bsLNR

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to reflect that and not just comment about it?  Are you wondering how to implement `test()`?  Inside `test()` one could plausibly argue that the two values are linked; *outside* `test()` where neither `funcArg` nor `f` are generic, those are both just union types and there's no guarantee anywhere that they are linked.  If you want to implement `test()` I can look further; otherwise I don't have anything more to add to my previous two comments and I'm still wondering how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: I've updated my question and code example. So the last line of code is incorrect as expected. So if the signature of `test` blocks invalid values of `funcArg`, why can't it be passed to `f`? I know the type of `f` is `'A' | 'B'`, but I want that to be restricted by the argument of `useComposable` inside the implementation of `test`.

Comment: It doesn't *quite* block invalid values; you can call `test(Math.random() < 0.99, "B")`, which will be bad 99% of the time. But at least there are approaches that will work here (which I'll look at when I can). Well, they work when using keylike types; there's not really a good way to do it for `boolean`, without making something crazy.  Again, the issue is described thoroughly at [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); have you looked at that issue?  The easiest approach here is going to be a type assertion, rather than trying to lead the compiler through your logic.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for the delay. Thank you for pointing out a case that won't work here. I've looked at the issue you mentioned, that seems to be the problem indeed. I'll rephrase what I said earlier about type assertions. It's not that it's unacceptable, rather if that I want to avoid them if there's a better alternative. It seems that for this case there isn't so I'll go that route for now. I am still interested in what you were going to say regarding " approaches that will work here". Would you mind sharing you ideas or pointing me to something in the TS docs?

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/WGYl2N) is the approach that will work, as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), although serializing booleans is .  Personally I'd rather use an assertion.  If that addresses the question well enough I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Yes, an assertion seems like the most logical choice here given the complexity the other solution would add in my real scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your implementation of `test()` is mostly that TypeScript isn't clever enough to see the correlation between `T` and `ArgType<T>` for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T extends boolean`.  The compiler essentially gives up and widens `T` to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `boolean`, in which case `const f = useComposable(composableArg).factory()` results in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions like `((arg: "A")=>void)|(arg: "B")=>void)`, and `funcArg` is a union `"A" | "B"`, and thus `f(funcArg)` is not safe because it's possible `f` accepts only `"A"` while `funcArg` is `"B"` (or vice versa).  Indeed, you can technically call `test()` with `T` actually being `boolean` as opposed to `true` or `false`:

```
test(Math.random() < 0.99, 'B');
```

which has a 99% chance of doing bad things at runtime, especially if `a` and `b` actually care about their argument being of the required type, as in:

```
const a: A = (arg: 'A') => { ({ A: "abc" })[arg].toUpperCase(); }
const b: B = (arg: 'B') => { ({ B: "abc" })[arg].toUpperCase(); }
```

There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) asking for a way to require that callers specify just one member of a union constraint instead of unions (so `T` would have to be specified as `true` or `false` and could not be `boolean`), but for now it's a possibility.  I'm not going to worry about this much from now on; let's assume that it's unlikely for someone to call `test()` in the bad way, and that the compiler should let you assume that `f` and `funcArg` are always correlated in the desired way.

---

The easiest approach here is to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that you know what you're doing.  You could do this with `funcArg as never`, which tells the compiler that `funcArg` is essentially *both* `"A"` *and* `"B"`, and so is safe no matter what `f` is.  This is fine, but I understand that it's uncomfortable to assert a blatant falsehood, since there are no actual values of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  A different approach is to assert `f` as `(arg: ArgType<T>) => void`, which is basically saying that whatever `funcArg` is, `f()` will accept it:

```
function test<T extends boolean>(composableArg: T, funcArg: ArgType<T>) {
  const { factory } = useComposable(composableArg)
  const f = factory();
  (f as (arg: ArgType<T>) => void)(funcArg); // okay
};
```

This assertion has a very good chance of being true, and is fairly straightforward.

---

The general inability of TypeScript to track correlations across union-typed expressions is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the suggested approach to these situations is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  This approach involves refactoring to use some "base" key-value mapping, and to express all operations in terms of generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that base type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that base type.  The refactoring is somewhat involved, and isn't always worth the effort; having the compiler verify your operations as safe is nice, but there are other considerations like having simple code.

Furthermore, the approach in ms/TS#47109 works when the value corresponding to `composableArg` is of a keylike type, such as a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  But in your case it's a `boolean`, which cannot be the key of an object in TypeScript.  We can still salvage it, because `boolean`s can be serialized in [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which TypeScript can see as a [template literal *type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), so that we end up with the string literals `"true"` and `"false"`.

Here's how it looks:

```
interface AT {
  true: 'A',
  false: 'B'
}

const mt: { [K in keyof AT]: (arg: AT[K]) => void } = {
  true: arg => { ({ A: "abc" })[arg].toUpperCase(); },
  false: arg => { ({ B: "abc" })[arg].toUpperCase(); }
}

function useComposable<B extends boolean>(arg: B) {
  function factory() {
    return mt[`${arg}`]
  }
  return { factory }
}

function test<B extends boolean>(composableArg: B, funcArg: AT[`${B}`]) {
  const { factory } = useComposable(composableArg);
  const f = factory();
  f(funcArg); // okay
};
```

Here `AT` is the "base" type, and we represent `mt` is an object of a mapped type over `AT` which holds functions corresponding to your `a` and `b`.  Then `useComposable` ends up referencing `` mt[`${arg}`] ``, which is of type `` (arg: AT[`${B}`]) => void ``.  And now when `funcArg` is of type `` AT[`${B}`] ``, the body of `test()` is seen as valid.  The callers see the same generic restrictions as your version, since `AT["true"]` is still `"A"` and `AT["false"]` is still `"B"`:

```
test(true, 'A'); // okay
test(true, 'B'); // error
```

So it's nice that there are no compiler errors where you don't expect them, but the cure is almost certainly worse than the disease here.  I'd rather use a type assertion and explicitly express my intent, than play games with generic mapped serialized boolean indices and make the compiler happy while confounding any human beings that read the code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuBLA9sEgN4BQSS2AnjMikgLxIAUImA5gFxIDkKPASkYA+JADd8uACblKNZACFGLNl14LBI8ZJmz4hKNiQhu9Jqw7c+mhqOIt7KbgCIQAI3jOkAXwEBtVQBdADpsfABVGFpMAGEQDGYBAG4fPQMjN24lc1UrDSFbEgckBRd3Tx9-INCIqKw4hOTU2QAzAFdgeDxCJDaMGPwwGHwodwAbCAAeABUkCAAPbAhgKSgkN3x8CZBgYQs1aaEyCgpqWiQAWSpp+WVZhaWVtexMNuQAflQkLNJZCnbOt0iC0EGFMFREtwrjdzscThRMBBsG1MER9khPiBvushPFLtd5H9mvDEcjUUUQV18ODUhRvL9TrcUBwYVMAEpzRbLVbrTbbXbKAAKbHASKwUEmRLZSJRwFZk2lZLl8kmZwg+BavX6g2GozcEwVwmEfh4lLBVB4gWEsmNAAZAr9Wh0ugQiEtDDNOY8eRsthAdnt9EMRuMIMyDgAaJAA+Dh0wslXTYRHIn6YCGCmg6lUHzKPoQAbBvUTZhB3Wh8MCVPpaPKM3ZxJJInMTV4-bx9jypMFUQSaQCFvOyuybxN2QvHNw07QbDMC4gbAAC2CmB2UkGiSQkyQtuCAE491GePkR0h4Av4IuWBAU-C01A-cExvh2MwbyPfvTSKBILAEMhpXrTASAZJBcGAJZMEpOhZinShXggKx+AjIkQTGDA8h4D80nTIwwGwbh7D8ABpMCiAAawgKgNVQaZAm4dtaJIwIe20aRcyYOCXjebhVC0exmEcMoPC8XwAg4EIwkiaIGggRsfBQ+E0Iw4wOH44pSiQVwRMqcT2Ek2oZPiOSmnpOlQJjIEtQLHUQ31KYlAebk1l9fk9lyEpbxOSzXWjLNwU3OCERlcl8L8AADAASYhVG8cKHXhMyTlJWVMypGkkq-f5nSs91sEmRyuSeXk-QDUtbOLMNLBKKMYzjJiouIBQ4pYkC7xrewgJzbw821ItQ3K-r7MrJt2tw2smC6xtUMHToRqQAB6BakHwciQCoEcx2nQxmG4iAj34JolpWtaNu22c9qPfIUmOrBMGpT8gA)